# Can fundamental maths be different in another world?

Tags: hard-science, mathematics

Mathematics is the language of sciences. Can the fundamentals be different in another world/universe?

A few things I'm pretty sure are *fundamental* don't change:

- $1 + 1 = 2$
- $\pi = \frac{circumference}{diameter}$
- Prime numbers
- trig functions
- Boolean logic ( 1 XOR 1 = 0 )

Things that I think are *not fundamental* (like standards):

- People using Base 10 vs Base 12
- Units of measurement (standards)

Things I'm not sure about:

- The golden ratio (people like it but it's the optimal pattern for many things in nature)

Comment: Mathematics itself is an exercise in logical deduction. Given x, y, and z it follows that ... These truths are true everywhere, because their truth is derived from definition. The same definitions will always lead to the same outcomes. Now this sense of truth is different from other senses of truth. It is true that on an euclidean geometry that two parallel lines will never intersect, but on a curved geometry the notion of parallel just loses meaning. The idea may never cross the minds of those whose world is dominated by curved geometry, and will change how maths is approached.

Comment: Pi can very well be different under different circumstances. It's constant in a _flat_ surface, not so on a curved surface; on such a surface Pi will depend on the curvature of the surface.

Comment: @Sach That's complete nonsense.  Pi is a mathematical constant.  It does **not** change under *any* circumstances.  You may be referring to some alternative definition based on physical measurement, but that is absolutely **not** how Pi is defined in mathematics.  Indeed it's use in mathematical physics is absolutely rooted in it's definition in mathematics, not measurement - it simply does not change.  Ever.

Comment: @StephenG, yes and no. The OP _defined_ Pi to be `Pi = c/d` and under that definition, it can definitely change. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/53023/could-pi-have-a-different-value-in-a-different-universe

Comment: @Sach  The OP asked about *fundamental* mathematics.  There's absolutely no way to fundamentally change Pi.  Also note if you use the OP's redefinition you no longer have Pi - you're defining something else, just abusing the name - the value of Pi remains unchanged.  Either way Pi is not changing.